# Is it fine if first response is private with AppCache (Symfony2)?

Tags: caching, symfony, cache-control, http-caching

I'm trying to use http caching. In my controller I'm setting a response as follows:

```
$response->setPublic();
$response->setMaxAge(120);
$response->setSharedMaxAge(120);
$response->setLastModified($lastModifiedAt);
```

**dev mode**

In dev environment first response is a 200 with following headers:

```
cache-control:max-age=120, public, s-maxage=120
last-modified:Wed, 29 Feb 2012 19:00:00 GMT
```

For next 2 minutes every response is a 304 with following headers:

```
cache-control:max-age=120, public, s-maxage=120
```

This is basically what I expect it to be.

**prod mode**

In prod mode response headers are different. Note that in app.php I wrap the kernel in AppCache.

First response is a 200 with following headers:

```
cache-control:must-revalidate, no-cache, private
last-modified:Thu, 01 Mar 2012 11:17:35 GMT
```

So it's a private no-cache response.

Every next request is pretty much what I'd expect it to be; a 304 with following headers:

```
cache-control:max-age=120, public, s-maxage=120
```

**Should I worry about it? Is it an expected behaviour?**

**What will happen if I put Varnish or Akamai server in front of it?**

I did a bit of debugging and I figured that response is private because of last-modified header. HttpCache kernel [uses EsiResponseCacheStrategy](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpCache/HttpCache.php#L210) to update the cached response ([HttpCache::handle()](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpCache/HttpCache.php#L171) method).

```
if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST === $type) {
    $this->esiCacheStrategy->update($response);
}
```

EsiResponseCacheStrategy [turns a response into non cacheable](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpCache/EsiResponseCacheStrategy.php#L42) if it uses either Last-Response or ETag ([EsiResponseCacheStrategy::add()](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpCache/EsiResponseCacheStrategy.php#L40) method):

```
if ($response->isValidateable()) {
    $this->cacheable = false;
} else {
    // ... 
}
```

[Response::isValidateable()](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php#L407) returns true if Last-Response or ETag header is present.

It results in [overwriting the Cache-Control header](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpCache/EsiResponseCacheStrategy.php#L62) ([EsiResponseCacheStrategy::update()](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpCache/EsiResponseCacheStrategy.php#L55) method):

```
if (!$this->cacheable) {
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, must-revalidate');

    return;
}
```

I asked this question on Symfony2 user group but I didn't get an answer so far: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/symfony2/6lpln11POq8/discussion

**Update.**

Since I no longer have access to the original code I tried to [reproduce the scenario with the latest Symfony standard edition](https://github.com/jakzal/symfony-standard/blob/cache/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Controller/DemoController.php#L62).

Response headers are more consistent now, but still seem to be wrong.

As soon as I set a `Last-Modified` header on the response, the first response made by a browser has a:

```
Cache-Control:must-revalidate, no-cache, private
```

Second response has an expected:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=120, public, s-maxage=120
```

If I avoid sending `If-Modified-Since` header, every request returns `must-revalidate, no-cache, private`.

It doesn't matter if the request was made in `prod` or `dev` environment anymore.

Comment: when i disable the $kernel = new AppCache($kernel); it is showed as public to me. but then it will always response with a code 200 ... i use as a revery proxy nginx.

Comment: are your `app.php` and `app_dev.php` the same ? (ignoring debug and env)

Comment: I have no access to that project anymore so I can't confirm this. I remember controllers were default ones with AppCache enabled.

Comment: @Florian I tried reproducing the problem and I've got a bit different behaviour with the latest Symfony version (see an update).

Comment: What is your *concrete* question? Which *concrete* issue do you have with those headers? What did you expect instead? Which practical problem is this causing to you? What did you wanted to do instead? Do you think a specific specification (like an RFC) is violated? If so which one and which part of it? The headers per-se *are* HTTP conform so your question is really broad.

Comment: The behaviour changed since I first asked the question (it was initially inconsistent between the environments). I guess it's now the question of interpretation of RFC and if the current behaviour is valid according to it or not. Since the first response with the Last-Modified header is private, I can answer myself that it's not valid according to the spec since it describes it as: response_is_fresh = (freshness_lifetime > current_age).

Comment: I'll double check that...

Comment: Could this be the case of small time differences between client and server?

Comment: Would you set `debug=>true` into getOptions() in AppCache so that you get `X-Symfony-Cache` header?

Comment: @Marek with Last-Modified time on the client doesn't matter as it should send the same value back (via If-Modified-Since).

Answer (score 9):

I have faced same problem. I had to supply 'public' headers my cdn. By default when gateway caching is enabled in prod mode, it returns 200 OK with private, nocache must validate headers.

I solved problem this way.

In app.php, before I send response to user ($respond->send), I have overwritten the cache control header to blank and set cache headers to public and max age(some value).

//code snippet from app.php

```
    $response = $kernel->handle($request);
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', '');
    $response->setPublic();
    $response->setMaxAge(86400);
    $response->send();
```

Comment: Did you get private responses despite the fact they were set public in a controller?

Comment: Yes, if I enable gateway caching and run it in prod mode. I needed above solution for static contents.

Answer (score -4):

The behavior you experience is intended. [Symfony2 Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html) explicitly describe the situations when *private* and *public* are used, default being *private*.

Comment: This is not my case, sorry.