# Symfony2 Reverse proxy has a cache control private

Tags: php, http, caching, symfony, reverse-proxy

I'm playing with Symfony2 Reverse proxy and HTTP cache and I had a lot of read on the subject.
However I'm getting stuck on how it works in my case.

Here is a use case.

`GET /api/articles` returns something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=12345; expires=Thu, 14-Nov-2013 14:50:35 GMT; path=/
age: 0
allow: GET, POST
cache-control: must-revalidate, no-cache, private
etag: "da4b6c4f1540a12a112936e58db06df8c95fd3c4"
vary: Accept,Accept-Encoding
x-content-digest: enbf30f962b06f99bd91843741537e112fbd3300c8
x-symfony-cache: GET /api/articles: miss, store
```

As you can see there the `Cache-Control` header is marked as private along with no-cache & must-revalidate. **However**, I think I'm setting the `Response` correctly:

```
    $response = clone $view->getResponse();
    $response
        ->setPublic()
        ->setEtag($etag)
        ->setSharedMaxAge(60)
        ->setVary(array('Accept'))
    ;
    if ($response->isNotModified($this->getRequest())) {

        return $response;
    }
```

I set it to Public so it should work. You may have noticed the `Set-Cookie` header, I dunno if it matters, but as long as I set the cache as public it shouldn't, isn't it?

Now, if I `GET /api/articles` with an `If-None-Match: {etag}` I get a 304 which is correct, but the `Cache-Control` header is the same.

Note that if I disable the Reverse Proxy, the Cache-Control is correct and showing me:

`Cache-Control: public, s-maxage=60` which is what I except.

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568074/is-it-fine-if-first-response-is-private-with-appcache-symfony2 (just for reference, no answer there yet)